# Android TabLayout detect when the last tab is reached

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I am developing an app which contains a TabLayout with tabs taken from a paginated server endpoint, i need to know when the last tab is visible (meaning when the tab bar is scrolled so as the last tab(where the title of the tab is written) becomes visible) so i can request the next page of tabs from the server. The only thing i could use is the `setOnScrollChangedListener` but it supports only Android `API Level 23` and higher.

How can i achieve this behaviour?

Thank you,

Comment: can you show us your code please

Comment: there is no code to show, i just want to know how to detect when the last tab in a TabLayout becomes visible

Comment: you can check on onPageSelected()

Comment: onPageSelected is called when i actually select the last tab, i want to know when the last tab becomes visible, not when it is selected, meaning the tab not the fragment attached to the tab, but the actual tab where the title of the tab is written

Comment: you want to change title when last tab becomes visible ?

Comment: i want to know when you scroll the tabs and you reach the last one and it becomes visible(when you can read the title of the last tab)

Comment: @NicusorFlorin any luck on this? I'm hoping to detect the same thing